# Assigning keys to function in insert mode also in vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to bind control-F to find dialog box in vim. Following code in .vimrc works:

```
:map <C-F> :promptfind<CR>
```

However, it works only in the command mode. How can I set it up so that it also works in insert mode?

Comment: The answer is laid out in quite some detail in `:help :map` or `:help map-commands`.

Comment: :imap in place of :map works in insert mode. But then this binding does not work in command mode. Maybe I need to place both :imap and :map statements. I am reading the help material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In insertmode, your binding will just insert `:promptfind` and then move to the new line. Use `<C-O>` to execute a single command-mode operation before going back to insert mode (`:help i_ctrl-o`), or `<Esc>` in its place to go to command mode and stay there afterwards.

```
:nnoremap <C-F> :promptfind<CR>
:inoremap <C-F> <C-O>:promptfind<CR>
```

Comment: I find that `:imap <C-F> <ESC>:promptfind<CR>i` and `:map <C-F> <ESC>:promptfind<CR>` are also working well.

Comment: The first one will produce unexpected results if the cursor is at the end of the line after `:promptfind`. Use `<C-O>`, it is there for a reason.